# mvn deploy:deploy-file RPM and tgz

Tags: maven, tar

I am able to deploy an RPM by itself using the following mvn command line options:

```
mvn -e deploy:deploy-file \
-Durl=http://repo.myorg.com/content/repo/snapshots \
-DrepositoryId=myorgsnapshots \
-DgroupId=com.myorg.mygroup \
-DartifactId=testApp \
-Dversion=1.0.15-SNAPSHOT \
-Dpackaging=rpm \
-Dfile="testApp-1.0.15-1.el6.x86_64.rpm"
```

I now want to also include a .tgz file along with the RPM.  What are the correct options to accomplish this task?  I've tried using `sources`, `files`, `types`, and `classifiers` options, as described **[here](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/deploy-file-mojo.html)** in various combinations with no effect, not even an error.

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution would be to have another execution of the [`deploy:deploy-file`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/deploy-file-mojo.html) goal.

There won't be any clash since both artifacts will have a different packaging: the first one is deployed with the `rpm` packaging and the second one is deployed with the `tgz` packaging. From [`packaging`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/deploy-file-mojo.html#packaging):

> Defaults to the file extension if it is not specified via command line or POM.

As such, you don't need to provide that argument, it will default to the extension.

The only cave-at is that the plugin will try to generate another POM for the second execution. From [`generatePom`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/deploy-file-mojo.html#generatePom):

> Will generate a default POM if none is supplied with the pomFile argument. Default: `true`

You can however disable that by setting `generatePom` to `false`.

```
mvn -e deploy:deploy-file \
-Durl=http://repo.myorg.com/content/repo/snapshots \
-DrepositoryId=myorgsnapshots \
-DgroupId=com.myorg.mygroup \
-DartifactId=testApp \
-Dversion=1.0.15-SNAPSHOT \
-Dfile="testApp-1.0.15-1.el6.x86_64.rpm"

mvn -e deploy:deploy-file \
-Durl=http://repo.myorg.com/content/repo/snapshots \
-DrepositoryId=myorgsnapshots \
-DgroupId=com.myorg.mygroup \
-DartifactId=testApp \
-Dversion=1.0.15-SNAPSHOT \
-DgeneratePom=false \
-Dfile="testApp-1.0.15-1.el6.x86_64.tgz"
```

Comment: Snapshots work but for releases, with  `-DgeneratePom=false`, I still get an error `Error installing artifact's metadata: Error while deploying metadata: Failed to transfer file`  I think creating a POM will be required.

Comment: @MichaelA.Jackson What is the exact error message and the exact steps you made?